# Rewriting directory-like URL-suffix as GET-parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Given the following setting I would like to do a mod_rewrite which I can not get to work:

I have a domain e.g. "example.org" pointing to a directory in a shared hosting environment e.g. `example/` with the following file structure:

```
example/
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

Now a URL like `example.org/test` should be rewritten to `example.org/index.php?p=test`. What I came up with is the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Unfortunately opening e.g. `example.org/test` in Firefox results in the following error:

**The page isn't redirecting properly**

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

- This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

It works though, if I prefix the matching part like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^prefix/([a-z]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then I can open e.g. `example.org/prefix/test` and am served with `index.php?p=test` although additional resources like CSS and JavaScript are not correctly referenced.

Who can help?